# Use TypeScript compiler from node

Tags: node.js, typescript

It's pretty easy to do this with coffee-script.

```
var coffee = require('coffee-script');
coffee.compile("a = 1");
//=> '(function() {\n  var a;\n\n  a = 1;\n\n}).call(this);\n'
```

Is there a way to do this with typescript?

**Edit:** also [posted on codeplex](http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/398049)

Comment: It appears that the TypeScript NPM module doesn't export any public interface. I've created [an issue to track this](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/97).

Comment: I would also recommend looking at the solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12717309/does-typescript-provide-an-explicit-public-api-for-nodejs-module-access

Comment: @ChristopherPappas that's funny, I was also planning on using this to make a brunch plugin. You have a repo somewhere I can check out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that nowadays there is a simpler solution, you can do:

```
let ts = require('typescript');
let source = ts.transpileModule('class Test {}', {}).outputText;
```

This results in:

```
"use strict";
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
    }
    return Test;
}());
```

Comment: Note: ts.transpile has been deprecated since this answer was posted. Here's some source material to back the answer above: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#transpiling-a-single-file

@topek feel free to update your answer with this info.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Note that ts.transpile is deprecated only because it has been superseded by the more extensible ts.transpileModule. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @AndrewFaulkner yeah that's why I linked to documentation on transpileModule, thought the user who posted the answer would update. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 8):

Since TypeScript's NPM module doesn't export any public interface, the only way to do this currently is to execute the `tsc` process.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var child = exec('tsc main.ts',
                function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
                    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
                    if (error !== null) {
                      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
                    }
                });
```

[An issue](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/97) has been opened to request a public interface for [the TypeScript module](https://npmjs.org/package/typescript).

Comment: Did they fix this in TypeScript 0.9?

Comment: Did they fix this in TypeScript 2.0 beta?

Comment: Did they fix this in TypeScript 2.2.1?

Comment: Did they fix this in TypeScript 2.4 RC? (jk, they fixed it much earlier)

Answer (score 8):

[better-require](https://github.com/olalonde/better-require) could help you achieve this.

It lets you require() typescript files - no pre-compilation needed - and a bunch of other file formats (coffeescript, clojurescript, yaml, xml, etc.)

```
require('better-require')();
var myModule = require('./mymodule.ts');
```

Disclosure: I wrote better-require.

Answer (score 6):

Check [this github project](https://github.com/niutech/typescript-compile) by niutech, it can convert TypeScript code to JS code on the fly **in browser**, but I guess it can be easily be modified to work in node.js.

I found it while I'm investigating the possibility of support TypeScript in my live, [firebug-inspired code editor](http://liveditor.com).

Answer (score 4):

Not answering the question directly, but since Googling for "run TypeScript from node directly" brings up this StackOverflow page, I figure I should add that you're able to do this with ts-node: https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node

Answer (score 0):

Official documentation about how to use TypeScript transpiler API to generate JavaScript source from a .ts file:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#user-content-transpiling-a-single-file

Official documentation about how to use TypeScript compiler API to compile a .ts file or a TS project to

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#user-content-a-minimal-compiler

(the later doesn't answer the original question but is very common to access /modify the AST and then transpile to object language so it could be usefull)